# In karate While trying to define a variable getting "no step-definition method match found for: def referenceId= response.referenceId"

Tags: karate

On trying to store a value from response in a variable ,to use it for the next post call and facing "no step-definition method match found for: def referenceId= response.referenceId" this error.

```
Feature: To test GET /leads/{id} API

# To generate test data for getLeads 
Scenario: Test with valid flow
Given url baseUrl+leads
And request {some valid request body}
When method post
Then status 200
* assert response.referenceId != null
* def referenceId= response.referenceId


Scenario: Test with get call
Given url baseUrl+getLeadsByID+referenceId
When method get
Then status 200
```

Till the assert step working fine. While trying to set referenceId getting this ."no step-definition method match found for: def referenceId= response.referenceId"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please keep white space around the `=` sign:

```
* def referenceId = response.referenceId
```

If you use the Eclipse or IntelliJ Cucumber IDE support - it will help avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have EXACTLY one whitespace on each side.
[Accidental] double/multiple whitespaces, like

```
* def referenceId  =  response.referenceId
```

won't work either.

Comment: this should no longer be an issue in 1.2.0 onwards